# How do I make a part, which is in Workspace, visible and start moving?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

The button, which I'm trying to use, is in StarterGUI. Don't know if it helps. Fairly new to scripting, however saw another post with something similar and used that code. Here is my code inside the LocalScript:

```
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local player = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local PurchaseEvent = ReplicatedStorage.PurchaseEvent
local productID = 1218445531

  
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    
    PurchaseEvent:FireServer(productID)
end)

if MarketplaceService:PlayerOwnsAsset(1218445531) then
    --Here is where the thing is supposed to happen
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to get a reference to the part, one way is to use something like `local part = workspace:WaitForChild("PartName")`

In order to make it visible, you need to set the transparency to 0. If you dont want the player walking through the part you may also need to turn collisions on with `CanColide`. Anchoring the part is also recommend to prevent it from falling.

```
part.Transparency = 0; -- makes it visible
part.CanColide = true; -- makes sure other objects cant go through this
part.Anchored = true; -- prevents the object from falling
```

There are many ways to make a part move. If the part is supposed to go from one place to another, and only has one destination, a Tween might be useful (see [TweenService](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/TweenService)).

Another way would be with a Heartbeat loop that changes the position each frame (see [RunService.Heartbeat](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/RunService/Heartbeat)). For example,

```
local keepMoving = true; -- change this to false to stop moving
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService");
local direction = Vector3.new(0, 1, 0); -- change this to anything you want
while (keepMoving) do
    local timePassed = RunService.Heartbeat:Wait(); -- wait one frame, roughly 0.016 of a second.
    part.Position += direction * timePassed; -- move the part in the direction 
end
```

This would move `part` up 1 stud every second.

Comment: Changing direction to Vector3.new(0, 0, 5) would make it 5 studs per second, and should be the same as adding 5 to the Z axis every second. The example in the answer is the same as adding 1 to the Y axis every second, which would move it up.

Comment: Now it works! This really helped me!

Comment: Since it works, could you mark this as the accepted answer?